# How to set "tabindex" on monaco editor programmatically or otherwise?

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm wondering if there's a way to set the "tabindex" on the editor programmatically or otherwise. In my application, monaco editor is part of a rather complex form (lying somewhere between regular HTML form field elements) where I need to define tabindex attributes on form field elements. I believe that the tabindex on the editor is set as "0". The problem it creates is that once I tab out of the editor, it jumps to an HTML element out of the order.

For example, please look at image below.

[image]

Ideally, when I press the tab key in the editor, the focus should go on the textbox for "LOCKED UNTIL" (1) and when I press shift+tab key in the editor, the focus should go on the textbox for "MESSAGE ID" (2). However, pressing the tab key puts the focus on the splitter (3) as both the splitter and the editor has the tabindex of "0".

Currently to fix this problem, I am capturing the `keyDown` event on the editor and setting the focus manually.

```
  editor.onKeyDown((evt) => {
    if (evt.keyCode === monaco.KeyCode.Tab) {
      if (evt.shiftKey) {
        $('#MessageId').select();
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
      } else {
        $('#MessageLockedUntil').select();
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
      }
    }
  });
```

I'm wondering if there's a better way of handling this?